# IdentityServer4: calling the connect/endsession endpoint and restoring session cookies: user is logged in again

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4

At our company we use IdentityServer for our authentication and authorization. One of the security policies our company asserts is that when you backup your cookies, log out (remove the local application cookies and redirect the user to the connect/endsession endpoint) and restore the cookies, that the user is **not** magically logged in again. With IdentityServer4, this is the case however.

I thought about creating a separate table in our database to save the IdentityServer sessions and when the connect/endsession endpoint is called, the session is removed from the database.

My question: is there an interface in IdentityServer4 that we can implement to:

1. save the session to a custom store (in our case our database)
2. delete the session if the connect/endsession endpoint is called
3. if the user hits the connect/authorize endpoint, IdentityServer4 looks in our custom store to check whether the current session is still valid.

I tried to create a class with the IUserSession because it has a RemoveSessionIdCookieAsync method, but it does not seem to be called upon logout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've implemented server-side storage for the cookies issued by our IDS4 implementation using the ITicketStore interface and setting the SessionStore property of the relevant CookieAuthenticationOptions.

Via this interface you have access to the AuthenticationTicket and thus all the info you need about the user and thus can store whatever you like in a DB to allow you to cleanup tickets for a given user when they sign out.

Using this method you will not have to modify any IDS4 behaviour as whether the user is currently authenticated or not is all handled by the cookie middleware.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. For anyone looking for more information, read this: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin.html